Energy exchange in transformers
In an ideal transformer, if the secondary coil is not present, will the energy be stored in the field of the primary coil? Is this the energy released if the current in an inductor decreases (back emf)? If yes, when the secondary coil is present, how will the inductor provide the back emf if it has given its stored energy to the secondary coil?

This question is similar to: Energy transfer in Transformers. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In an ordinary wire, energy is stored in the field around the wire. This is not how people often think about it. They think of electrons pushing each other through the wire. Here is a Veritasium video explaining it How Electricity Actually Works.

This is a follow on video to his original video on the topic. The first one was confusing. He gives a better explanation in this one. There is also a lot of talk about reactions to and problems with the first video. He really needs a 3rd video that just has the good explanation. But he still gets the point across.
You might find the other videos he references helpful.

You might also find this post helpful. How is energy "stored in an electric field"?. You might find Perter - Reinstate Monica's answer the most useful.
